# Get particular value from comma separated values

Tags: mysql, html, join

I have two tables Subjects And Faculty.

Subjects Table

```
subjects_id  subjects_name
    1             Maths    
    2            Science
    3            Geography
    4             History
    5             English
```

Faculty table

```
fact_id  faculty_name  subjects_id
   1         Roy          1,2,3
   2         James         4,5
```

Now what i want is to display subject which are taught by Roy in a drop-down(html5).I am confused as in how will i achieve it as the subjects_id are comma separated. I know i will have to use joins but not sure how to actually use it.
Please do help me.

Comment: Consider asking/googling for 2 separate questions: 1) how to perform an SQL join between two tables, when foreign keys are stored as comma-separated list ; 2) how to execute mysql query in [your_back_end_of_choice]

Comment: Sir i have searchd on the web that storing comma seperated values is a bad design.So how can i achieve this please do help me

Comment: Normally you store foreign keys on separate rows. E.g. `1    Roy    1`, `1    Roy    2`, `1    Roy    3`.

Comment: but sir wont it give error cos my fact_id coloum is primary

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select * from subjects
where FIND_IN_SET(subjects_id,(select subjects_id from faculty where fact_id = 1)) <> 0
```

Subjects for Roy (id = 1)